# Plot non-continuous time series with Matplotlib as datetime not string

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime

I'm trying to plot date vs num with these datasets

```
                    date    num
0   22/12/2022 09:09    7.92
1   22/12/2022 09:09    7.95
2   22/12/2022 09:09    7.98
3   22/12/2022 09:09    7.95
4   22/12/2022 09:09    7.93

... ... ...

4514    23/12/2022 14:48    5.68
4515    23/12/2022 14:48    5.68
4516    23/12/2022 14:48    5.69
4517    23/12/2022 14:48    5.70
4518    23/12/2022 14:48    5.66
```

When the date column type is a string it gets the correct plot

```
data_1.plot(x='date',y='num')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
```

[image]

However, when I converted the date to datetime, it plotted datetime which doesn't exist in data

```
data_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_1['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
data_1.plot(x='date',y='num')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
```

[image]

Do you know what is the problem? I'm having a hard time searching for the solution, thank you

**Updated**
thanks for editing my question and giving me the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508613/is-there-a-matplotlib-hack-to-plot-time-series-data-continuously-with-missing-ho), but still the solution is suggesting to convert to string not solve the problem using datetime

Comment: What do you mean by "plotting datetime that doesn't exist" Are you referring to the line that connects the values in between ~12h Dec 22 and ~9h Dec 23 ?

Comment: It seems like there is a large gap in your time series (between ~22-12 12:00 and 23-12 10:00), Matplotlib simply connects the last data point on 22-12 with the first on 23-12. You can check this by making e.g. a `scatter()` plot.

Comment: @FObersteiner yeah i'm referring the line, i want to plot without that line in datatime format

Comment: @Bart indeed there is gap between in those data, that's how the data is, my goal is to plot how the number change in different days with line plot

Comment: You could insert NaNs, as described in [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/masked_demo.html)

Comment: @FObersteiner in that case, i need to add gap date to datasets with NaN values?

Comment: I'd probably try to resample the data to a fixed frequency. That will create NaN where you have no data (num column). However, that requires a monotonically increasing datetime index (unique timestamps). Your timestamps seem to be minutes only, so what's the original frequency?

Comment: related: [Python: Matplotlib avoid plotting gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27266987/10197418)

Comment: @FObersteiner turns out NaN values only hide the gap and leave the blank space, what i wants to remove the gap and connect the the line like i plotted using date string

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. You cannot do that with a datetime axis. You must use a categorial axis, i.e. datetime as string. As described in the question linked by Bart.